# Como aplicar um setNull(index,Types.Blob)?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Como posso inserir null na base de dados se uma imagem não for carregada?

```
FileInputStream cabecalho = null;
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
File fileLogotipo = new File(imagemCabecalho); //imagemCabecalho = path
cabecalho = new FileInputStream(fileCabecalho);

if (imagemCabecalho.equals("") || imagemCabecalho == null) {
                ps.setNull(2, Types.BLOB);
            } else {
                 ps.setBinaryStream(2, cabecalho, (int) fileCabecalho.length());
            }
```

Isto não me está a funcionar, o que é que devo colocar na condição 'if' para setar null ?

**Atualização:**

Dá-me esse erro:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at faturacao.ConfEmpresa.jButtonRegistarActionPerformed(ConfEmpresa.java:3126)
    at faturacao.ConfEmpresa.access$6300(ConfEmpresa.java:46)
    at faturacao.ConfEmpresa$62.actionPerformed(ConfEmpresa.java:1751)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, `imagemCabecalho` é o caminho para um arquivo. Logo, o código pode não funcionar porque você tem um caminho, mas o arquivo não existe.

Seria interessante verificar isso, talvez da seguinte forma:

```
if (imagemCabecalho == null || imagemCabecalho.length == 0 || !new File(imagemCabecalho).exists()) {
    ps.setNull(2, Types.BLOB);
} else {
    FileInputStream cabecalho = new FileInputStream(fileCabecalho);
    ps.setBinaryStream(2, cabecalho, (int) new File(imagemCabecalho).length());
}
```

Comment: tentei adicionar esse !new File(imagemCabecalho).exists()) mas dá erro :S Vou colocar o erro em cima. Desde já agradeço a ajuda

Comment: @HugoMachado Eu copiei o seu exemplo e não me atentei que estava testando `.equals` e depois `== null`. Não pode ser assim, a comparação com `null` tem que sempre vir primeiro. Veja meu novo exemplo que deve corrigir isso.